# Big Objects are not inserting properly but got successful message while inserting

Tags: apex, soql, data-migration, big-object

I have inserted 50 records from email message (standard objects) to big objects by apex(database.insertimmediate). All 50 records are inserted successfully. But in big objects, i could see only 8 records. What is the problem with it?